# Structuring webpack config for use with karma testing

Tags: karma-runner, webpack

I would like to create a test suite which will be run with `karma` against my app which is using webpack to build itself. I have two entrypoints, `app` and `vendors`. These are set up through [my `webpack.config.js` file here](https://gist.github.com/marr/b1c36014626e03acc38a#file-webpack-config-js). The resulting bundle.js should contain both of these entrypoints in its generated file.
My karma (mocha) tests residing in `test/spec/*_spec.js` are currently pointing to specific components, via require statements like:

`var app = require('../src/scripts/App')`

They also utilize react/jsx which seems to be causing problems during the test run where I get jsx errors:

`Module parse failed: /Users/dmarr/src/status/test/spec/app_spec.js Line 10: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

I'd like to keep test runs quick as possible as well as fast build times for testing with `webpack-dev-server` during development by minimizing babel transforms to only where needed.

What do I need to do in karma.conf.js to get my builds working? [Here is the karma.conf.js file I'm playing around with](https://gist.github.com/marr/b1c36014626e03acc38a#file-karma-conf-js).

Note, that I do have this working without breaking out the vendor bundle here: https://github.com/bitwise/status

Thanks for any help,
Dave

Comment: did you find an answer to this? i'm getting a similar error: `ERROR in ./app/components/game.js
Module parse failed: \app\components\game.js Unexpected token (30:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Answer (score 1):

In a similar setup, disabling CommonsChunkPlugin (for testing only) worked for me. Give it a shot!